# Bibtex Chicago Style: need to change truncaation setting for lists of three or more authors

Tags: bibtex, natbib, chicago-style, harvard-style

I am using Bibtex, Natbib and Chicago Style. However, I need a changed format for authors. If there are 3 or more authors, only the first one should be mentioned, followed by "et al.". At the moment, all three authors are mentioned and only for 4 or more authors, "et al." appears. How can I change that?

The solution must be hidden somewhere in this code:

```
FUNCTION {format.rem.names}
{ 's :=
  'f :=
  #2 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames #1 - 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr f format.name$ 't :=
      nameptr #1 >
    { namesleft #1 >
        { ", " * t * }
        {
        ", " *
         t "others" =
        { " et~al." * }
        { " \harvardand\ " * t * }
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
    't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The presence of the macro `\harvardand` in the code excerpt you've posted indicates that the code comes from one of the seven bibliography style files of the [harvard](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/harvard/) citation management package: `agsm`, `apsr`, `dcu`, `jmr`, `jphysicsB`, `kluwer`, and `nederlands`. A quick check reveals that of these seven candidate files, *only two* styles-- `apsr` and `jmr` -- feature a function called `format.rem.names`. A further check reveals that of these two styles, only `apsr` truncates lists of authors (or editors) to "firstauthor et al." only if there are *at least four authors/editors*; in contrast, the `jmr` style truncates the list whenever there are three or more authors/editors.

Let us proceed, then, under the assumption that you're actually using the `apsr` bibliography style, rather than the style called `chicago`. It turns out that the function `format.rem.names` is *not* the place to look for if you want to change the truncation behavior so that "firstauthor et al." is shown whenever the piece has three or more authors/editors. One way to verify this claim is to note that the function `format.rem.names` is *identical* in `apsr` and `jrm`; since their truncation settings are not identical, the difference must occur in some other function.

Instead, you need to look inside the function `format.lab.names.abbr`, which looks like this in `apsr.bst`:

```
FUNCTION {format.lab.names.abbr}
{ 's :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames #1 >
    { numnames #3 >
    { s #1 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$ " et~al." * }
    { s format.lab.names.full }
      if$
    }
    { s #1 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$ }
  if$
}
```

The key code sequence is the "inner" if clause, viz.,

```
    { numnames #3 >
    { s #1 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$ " et~al." * }
    { s format.lab.names.full }
      if$
```

Freely translated, this code snippet says: "If the variable 'numnames' (which contains the number of authors/editors of the piece) is *greater than* 3, write the string 's' (which will contain the formatted string of authors, to be used in the citation call-out) as 'firstauthor et~al.'. Otherwise, i.e., if the number of authors is either 2 or 3, invoke the function `format.lab.names.full`." (The "outer" if clause is true if there is *more than 1* author.)

What to do? Well, just change

```
    { numnames #3 >
```

to

```
    { numnames #2 >
```

(In my copy of the file `apsr.bst`, this code snippet occurs on line 572.)

Please do *not* modify/edit the original file (`apsr.bst`) directly. Instead, make a copy of the file and call the copy, say, `apsr-mod.bst`. Apply the suggested edit in `apsr-mod.bst`, and then save `apsr-mod.bst` to the directory that contains your main tex file. Finally, be sure to (a) change `\bibliographystyle{apsr}` to `\bibliographystyle{apsr-mod}` in your main tex file and (b) re-run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX *twice more* to fully propagate all changes.

Comment: You are great! Ingenious!!! Everything you have writte is right. I really used the aspr style and adapted it (few month ago). Thank you so much!!!